# how to transform a IO [FilePath] into a [FilePath]?

Tags: haskell, monads

I would like to look in my current directory and only print `.zip` files.

My strategy (shown below) is to get the FilePaths as an `IO [FilePath]`. I thought I could lift the `IO` so that it would be possible to filter on string elements.

What is wrong in my thinking? I wonder if it is a problem that I use `liftIO` on an `IO [FilePath]` instead of `IO FilePath`.

```
import System.Directory 
import System.FilePath.Glob
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

main :: IO()

listCompressedImages folder = 
  filter (match (compile ".zip")) (liftIO (getDirectoryContents folder))

main = listCompressedImages "." >>= print
```

Comment: *Never, never, never* use `liftIO`! If you're using `liftIO`, you're practicing awful Haskell. I realise that you're new, but you need to learn!

Comment: @AJFarmar What the heck? `liftIO` is very useful, and certainly not awful Haskell. It's not necessarily helpful here, but your advice to avoid it at all costs seems way off target.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a canonical `IO a -> a` question; but I've found one that is pretty close. If you can find a better one, please ping me.

Comment: @daniel wagner. I agree that the other question offer an answer applicable for me - should I delete my question?

Comment: @hotGopher No reason to delete it, I think. Marking as duplicate is sufficient (which is already done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not extract anything from `IO`, but you can adapt the other functions to work on `IO` values

```
listCompressedImages folder = 
   filter (match (compile ".zip")) `fmap` getDirectoryContents folder
```

The above `fmap` applies a pure function (as `filter ...`) to some `IO` value. Note that the resulting type will still be `IO` -- again, you can never escape the `IO` monad.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to use `liftIO` here, that's for lifting an `IO` action to a more complex monad, not for extracting a value from an `IO` action.  In short, you can't turn `IO a` into `a`.  The whole point of `IO` is to *prevent* you from doing this.  You can work with the `a` value directly using `do` notation, though:

```
listCompressedImages :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
listCompressedImages folder = do
    -- getDirectoryContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
    -- contents :: [FilePath]
    contents <- getDirectoryContents folder
    -- filter (match (compile ".zip")) :: [FilePath] -> [FilePath]
    return $ filter (match (compile ".zip")) contents

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- compressedImages :: [FilePath]
    compresssedImages <- listCompressedImages "."
    print compressedImages
```

Whenever you have something with the type `IO a` and you want to get the value of type `a` from it, use `do` notation and extract it using `<-`.  For a more in-depth explanation I'll defer to [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Comment: thank you. I guess I need it in tea spoons sometimes. The logic is that filter applies the function match (with a pattern) on each element in content, right? when I add a t.zip file to my folder this still returns an empty list..

Comment: I found out I needed to use (compile "*.zip") (wildcard).